# Function Plotter

Tags: windows, plot

There is a nice function plotter built into OSX. Has anyone found something free that runs on windows (with out having to go through Cygwin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolframalpha.com

excellent for many branches of academia. it also plots.

Comment: Although hardly "something free that runs on windows" (well, apart frm the "free" part).

Comment: Wolframalpha.com doesn't run on windows for you? It does for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about [MathGV - Function Plotting Software](http://www.mathgv.com/)?

Also, [DME Calculator](http://www.dme-spm.com/freeware.html) is a calculator that can plot functions.

> The DME calculator is an advanced
>   calculator for Windows. It is a part
>   of the program package for controlling
>   our instruments. However, in its basic
>   version it can be of use for anyone
>   who wishes to make calculations with a
>   PC or wishes to solve somewhat more
>   complex problems without having to use
>   a large spreadsheet program package.
>   The DME calculator fits on a diskette
>   and starts without any notable waiting
>   time.

Answer (score 1):

If by functions, you mean mathematical functions, there is a nice list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_graphing_software) which has plenty of suggestions.